# MySQL можно ли при использовании SELECT как-то ссылаться на предыдущую строку выборки?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `num` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

заполненная значениями num, например: 2, 5, 20.

Можно ли как-то сделать выборку типа:

```
SELECT num,num-[num из предыдущей выбранной строки] FROM test
```

чтобы получить на выходе такой ответ:

```
2, NULL
5, 3
20, 15
```

Comment: Думал это пояснение, оказалось операция) Если порядок не меняется, то можно как-то так: `SELECT t.num, (t.num - (SELECT num FROM test WHERE id < t.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)) as prev_num FROM test t`

Comment: @InDevX, подойдёт такой вариант, спасибо! Действительно, можно к id привязаться...

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать функцию `LAG()` (доступна начиная с `MySQL 8.0.22`), которая позволяет выбирать значение столбца из предыдущей строки.

Как результат получится запрос:

```
SELECT num, LAG(num) OVER (ORDER BY id) - num AS diff
FROM test;
```

Comment: Стоит добавить что она доступна начиная с mysql 8.0.22

Comment: Интересный вариант, спасибо. Но версия 8+ точно не для меня.